# Multiple themes changing tab icon color

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-theme

I have been learning [MDC from google code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-103-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0), and it is a well designed application to know how material design works. However, in a particular section they showed how to use dark theme. The did it by changing the theme attributes from `style.xml`. Being resourceful, I have been trying to learn how to use multiple theme and interchange them runtime.

For this reason I avoided their hard-coded way and tried to inherit the base theme and put changes according to my need. Below I am putting some changes in the theme file

```
<!--Dark Theme style !-->
<style name="Theme.Shrine.Dark" parent="Theme.Shrine">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/darkTextColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/darkColorControlActivated</item>
    <item name="toolBarStyle">@style/Widget.Shrine.Toolbar.Dark</item>
    <item name="appBackGroundColor">@color/darkBackgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

There are some changes but they are irreverent to my problem, so I am not going to add them here. Anyway, with changes in my style file app looks something like this
[image]

Everything is expected except for icon colour in toolbar. So I check into the code and find every icon colour is referenced from the their respective from drawable file with `android:tint="@color/toolbarIconColor"` and in `color.xml` toolbarcolor is `<color name="toolbarIconColor">@color/textColorPrimary</color>`

It shows wrong color in dark mode, in this case how can I show yellow color in dark mode. I have changed textColoeSecondary from base theme of dark theme but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to remove hard reference of colour from every drawables which reflect different colours depending on app theme. So, add `attrs.xml` in your values directory. and add the reference name for icon colour such as this one

```
<attr name="toolbarIconColor" format="reference"/>
```

Secondly, add two different colour for two themes. For example, for normal theme `<color name="toolbarIconColor">@color/textColorPrimary</color>` and for dark one use `<color name="darkToolbarIconColor">#FFCF44</color>`

Finally, go to your `style.xml` file and make this change to hook up with the reference we have added in `attrs.xml` file, like this one for normal theme `<item name="toolbarIconColor">@color/toolbarIconColor</item>` and `<item name="toolbarIconColor">@color/darkToolbarIconColor</item>`